# JS - How to delete all routes generated with Google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a project where I need to display routes between 2 markers.
I found this post which I customized and it works quite well (thanks a lot for it BTW):
[Google Maps Api straight (shortest) route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037639/google-maps-api-straight-shortest-route/39467916#39467916)

Now when the user selects another address/marker, the new routes are displayed, but the old ones remain there too, so obviously I need to get rid of them before rendering the new ones.
I struggled for days, but I keep getting all kinds of errors. (I admit, my JS skill is still average...)

I think the bit that renders them is this:

```
      //painting the routes in green blue and red
      routesResponses.forEach(function (res) {
        res.routes.forEach(function (rou, index) {
          new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
         // directionsRenderer({
            map: map,
            directions: res,
            routeIndex: index,
            polylineOptions: {
              strokeColor:
                rou.legs[0].duration.value == fastest
                  ? "red"
                  : rou.legs[0].distance.value == shortest
                  ? "darkgreen"
                  : "blue",
              strokeOpacity:
                rou.legs[0].duration.value == fastest
                  ? 0.8
                  : rou.legs[0].distance.value == shortest
                  ? 0.9
                  : 0.5,
              strokeWeight:
                rou.legs[0].duration.value == fastest
                  ? 9
                  : rou.legs[0].distance.value == shortest
                  ? 8
                  : 3,
            },
          });
        });
      });
```

But because there is "new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer" inside foreach loop, I don't know how to get those objects and remove them.
I tried moving the `new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer` above in the global scope, but then I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: directionsRenderer is not a function".

Answer (score 2):

Because you have multiple `DirectionsRenderer` object that you are creating, you should use an array to store them.

Create a function which will loop over this array and call the `setMap(null)` method to remove the `DirectionsRenderer` instances from the map. After that clear the array.

Place this in a scope where it is available for your `routesResponses` loop.

```
const directionRenderers = [];

function removeDirectionRenderers() {
  directionRenderers.forEach(directionRenderer => {
    directionRenderer.setMap(null));
  });
  directionRenderers.length = 0;
}
```

Before adding your `DirectionsRenderer` instances, call the remove function first. The instances should now be removed from the map and the array should be cleared.

```
// Remove all 
removeDirectionRenderers()

//painting the routes in green blue and red
routesResponses.forEach(function (res) {
  res.routes.forEach(function (rou, index) {
    const directionRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      map: map,
      directions: res,
      routeIndex: index,
      polylineOptions: {
        strokeColor:
        rou.legs[0].duration.value == fastest
          ? "red"
          : rou.legs[0].distance.value == shortest
          ? "darkgreen"
          : "blue",
        strokeOpacity:
        rou.legs[0].duration.value == fastest
          ? 0.8
          : rou.legs[0].distance.value == shortest
          ? 0.9
          : 0.5,
        strokeWeight:
        rou.legs[0].duration.value == fastest
          ? 9
          : rou.legs[0].distance.value == shortest
          ? 8
          : 3,
      },
    });

    // Add to the array.
    directionRenderers.push(directionRenderer);
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, no disrespect, but just to say, I believe the duplicate question is actually slightly different and the answer the same. In practice, I didn't understand or couldn't extract a solution for my problem from that one I'm afraid, but I could from the above answer (thanks a lot, Emiel Zuurbier!!!).
So in conclusion, I definitely think these side questions (similar, duplicates) are beneficial for everybody. 
I don't mind at all the downvote, but I definitely see the benefit of multiple variations of the same root/main questions.